# DFP iOS There is no required value

Tags: ios, google-dfp

For advertising in the project I use the "`DFP`" service. I set up the "`Native app install ad`" for mobile advertising, fill in the required fields, and in the "`Image`" field I load the picture 1200 × 627 pixels, then adjust the remaining fields when I try to save the settings , It gives an error - "`There is no required value`"

screen service DFP

[image]

screen size my image load

[image]

Answer (score 0):

problem with Safari browser, I try on Chrome, all work!!!